# How to wrap/hook/proxy `eval` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, proxy, scope, eval

Say there is a javascript [S1]:

```js
(function(){ var localvar='test';eval('console.log(localvar)'); })();
```

Run [S1] will output "test" without superise.

I want to trace `eval`, so I write a `myeval` that wrap the `eval` [S2]:

```js
var myeval = function(s){ return eval(s); };
```

Run [S1] with little modify [S3]:

```js
(function(){ var localvar='test';myeval('console.log(localvar)'); })();
```

it throw an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: localvar is not defined`.

The error is caused by running `eval` in a wrong scope/context (scope of `myeval`), so it's there any way to wrap/trace `eval`? Or, it's there any way to get caller's scope?

Comment: At first glance, I don't think so, but this is a very weird issue to be having - it sounds like an X/Y problem to me

Comment: You can `try {} catch(e){}` anywhere to catch it, but there's no solution. Pretty dangerous to be playing around with eval too. If you write code, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @somethinghere I don't care the exception, but caller that called `myeval` will see a different behavior than invoking original `eval`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought that, the `eval` is a specifal implement in native, so it can getting caller's scope/context.